# R Error in 'for' and 'if' statement in making survival dataset

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to make survival dataset with event and time.

The dataset is assessed four times repeatedly. `firs` means the first observation, `seco` means the second observation ... and so on.

Event is defined as that observed value become the half of first observation.

The time is the time when event happen, so if 5 in `firs` become 2 in `thir`, the time is 3.

If no event happens until four, event is 0 and time is 4.

If missing happens, event is 0 and time is that time.

```
set.seed(1234)
firs<-sample(x=1:10,size=10)
seco<-sample(x=1:10,size=10)
thir<-sample(x=1:10,size=10)
four<-sample(x=1:10,size=10)
set<-as.data.frame(cbind(firs,seco,thir,four))
set$crit<-set$firs/2
set[2,3]<-NA
set[9,2]<-NA
set

   firs seco thir four crit
1     2    7    4    5  1.0
2     6    5   NA    3  3.0
3     5    3    2    9  2.5
4     8   10    1    4  4.0
5     9    2    8    2  4.5
6     4    9    5    7  2.0
7     1    6    9    1  0.5
8     7    1   10   10  3.5
9    10   NA    6    6  5.0
10    3    4    7    8  1.5
```

So, in this dataset, the time and event will be

```
   time event
1   4     0
2   3     0
3   3     1
4   3     1
5   2     1
```

... and so on

I'm trying to make code with `for` and `if` statement. However, it generated error.

for example,

```
for(i in 2:4){
  if(set[,i]<set$crit){
    set$event<-1
    set$time<-i-1
  }else if(set[,i]>set$crit)
  {set$event<-0
  set$time<-i}
}
Warning messages:
1: In if (set[, i] < set$crit) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (set[, i] > set$crit) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (set[, i] < set$crit) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (set[, i] > set$crit) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In if (set[, i] < set$crit) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
6: In if (set[, i] > set$crit) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Would you let me know what was the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: The length  is more than 1 `if(set[,i]<set$crit` you may need `ifelse`

Comment: For the 4 columns, why you have only one 'event' column in expected.  Do you need `rowSums(set[1:4] < set$crit[col(set[1:4])], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun (sorry for ctrl+k doesn't work in comment in chrome) I made the code like below, but the error appeared again. Would you let me know what was the problem?

for(i in 2:4){
  ifelse(set[,i]<set$crit,
    set$event<-1 & set$time<-{{i}}, if(set[,i]>set$crit)
  {set$event<-0
  set$time<-{{i}}})
}

Error in 1 & set$time <- { : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object

Comment: It's about 'incidence' of survival analysis. Survival analysis is about the earliest event and its time. Events after the earliest are censored.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code and get answer

```
x <- unique(set$time)
for(i in length(x))
```

this will definately help. answer to your warning this is because of if condition. it only refer one value when if condition is there, in your data when if condition you have applied then observation is more then one.